# Parse: Log in existing user via Instagram

Tags: parse-platform, oauth, instagram-api

In our Parse-based app [8pics](http://8ight.pics) we want to give users the chance to log in with Facebook or Instagram. Facebook is no problem, but I'm stuck with Instagram.

I used the Instagram API to get an access token and a user ID, which I then compare with our Parse database to get the valid user. The question is, how can I log that user in?

The Parse blog explains how to [log someone in if I have a session token](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/bring-your-own-login/), but to do that, I'd have to create a session first, which is not only not explained in the docs, but discouraged. So if I have the Instagram access token AND the PFUser it belongs to, but not their password, how do I create a session and log the user into that session?

**Edit:** I ended up finding a solution via Cloud Code in this tutorial: [link](https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app)

Basically now I solve it by setting a random password in Cloud Code and then logging the user in, which obviously resets the user's password. Is there a way without resetting the password, i.e. so that a user can later either log in with Instagram or with Email/Password?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that it is the only solution. It feels totally wrong though.